# How to mock a void method that changes state of instance property

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

In this class Foo, I have a method to initialize a filter which uses a Set data structure. NOTE: Assume dependency injection of `namesToFilter` is not allowed in Foo class

```
public class Foo {

   Set<String> namesToFilter;

   public Foo() {
       namesToFilter = new HashSet<>();
       initialize();
   }  

   void initialize() {
     namesToFilter.add("XYZ");
     namesToFilter.add("ABC");
   }

}
```

How to mock `initialize` method in mockito so that I can test other cases like
namesToFilter.add("PQR") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Foo instance and change the namesToFilter Set.

You can use Whitebox (import org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.Whitebox;) for that.

Example:

```
Set set = (Set) Whitebox.getInternalState(instance, "namesToFilter");
```

Now you can change the set as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice using the PowerMock and mock the Foo class partially.

As the test class should be on same package level, it should be possible.

```
Foo partialMocked = createMockBuilder(Foo.class)
.addMockedMethod("initialize").createMock();

expect(partialMocked.initialize()).andAnswer(new IAnswer<Void>() {
            public Void answer() throws Throwable {
                partialMocked.namesToFilter = preInitFilters;
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

UnitTests verify *public observable behavior*, not "code".

Your test is highly coupled to the implementation of  class `Foo`. But one of the main purposes of UnitTests is verify that changes in implementation do not change the *behavior* of the unit unintentionally.

If you want to change how `Foo` stores the "names to filter" you also have to change your UnitTest. Therefore you are in the risk, that you change your UnitTest to verify a unintentionally changed behavior without any chance to observe this.

If your UnitTest would only verify the units communication with its dependencies the change in the classes implementation would not require a change in the UnitTest. Therefore you're sure that the  UnitTest still  verifies the intended behavior.